# Mergesort - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, mergesort, double-pointer

Code directory structure,

```
./Computing$ ls -LR
.:
list file.txt  mergeSort.c  program.exe type.h

./list:
arrayImpl.c  linkedListImpl.c  list.h
```

---

Compilation procedure:

```
$./Computing
gcc -Wall -Werror -DARRAY -I. mergeSort.c ./list/*.c -o program
```

---

### [Here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/code) is the complete code having files, `mergeSort.c`, `list/*`, `type.h`

With the given representation of `List`,

```
typedef struct List{
  void **array;

  /* Housekeeping - Array enhancement/shrink */
  int lastItemPosition;
  int size;
}List;
```

---

mergesort is performed below on `list->array`, where `aux` maintains the shallow copy of `array`

```
void mergeSort(List *list, size_t listSize, isLess less){

  if(list != NULL){

    void **aux = malloc(list->size * sizeof(void*)); //Auxillary shadow copy
    if(aux != NULL){
      printf("Size of list: %d\n", listSize);
      mSort(list->array, aux, 0, listSize-1, less);
    }else{

      fprintf(stderr, "mergeSort() - Malloc failure");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }else{

    fprintf(stderr, "mergeSort() - List is NULL");
  }
}

static void mSort(void **array, void **aux, int low, int high, isLess less){

  if(high <= low) return;
  int mid = (low + high)/2;

  mSort(array, aux, low, mid, less);
  mSort(array, aux, mid+1, high, less);
  merge(array, aux, low, mid, high, less);
}

static void merge(void **array, void **aux, int low, int mid, int high, isLess less){

  for(int index = 0; index <= high; index++){
    aux[index] = array[index]; //Shallow copy
  }
  printf("Low-%d, Mid-%d, High-%d\n", low, mid, high);
  int leftIndex = low; int rightIndex = mid+1;
  printf("leftIndex-%d, rightIndex-%d\n", leftIndex, rightIndex);

  for(int index = 0; index <= high; index++){

    if(leftIndex > mid)    /* right array exhausted */  array[index] = aux[rightIndex++];
    else if(rightIndex > high) /*left array exhausted*/ array[index] = aux[leftIndex++];
    else if( less(aux[rightIndex], aux[leftIndex]) )    array[index] = aux[rightIndex++];
    else                                                array[index] = aux[leftIndex++];
  }

}
```

---

where the use code is,

---

```
bool less(const void *key, const void *item){
  printf("\nIn less function\n");
  printf("left-%d, Right-%d\n\n", ((Record *)key)->age, ((Record *)item)->age);
  if( ((Record *)key)->age < ((Record *)item)->age ){
    printf("Return true\n");
    return true;
  }else{
    printf("Return false\n");
    return false;
  }
}

int main(){
  FILE *pFile = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  checkHandleFailure(pFile, FILE_HANDLE_FAILURE);
  char buf[MAX_RECORD_SIZE];
  DBCache *cache = initCache(pFile);


  readHeader(pFile, cache, buf);

  readData(pFile, cache, buf);

  printRecords(cache);

  printf("Before calling mergesort() \n");
  mergeSort(cache->records, listGetSize(cache->records), less);
}
```

---

---

Actual output is:

```
$ ./program.exe
Age,LastName,FirstName
------------------------------
50,B,A

30,A,B

20,X,D

10,F,A

90,V,E

60,N,M

Records#: 6
Before calling mergesort()
Size of list: 6
Low-0, Mid-0, High-1
leftIndex-0, rightIndex-1

In less function
left-30, Right-50

Return true
Low-0, Mid-1, High-2
leftIndex-0, rightIndex-2

In less function
left-20, Right-30

Return true
Low-3, Mid-3, High-4
leftIndex-3, rightIndex-4

In less function
left-90, Right-10

Return false
Low-3, Mid-4, High-5
leftIndex-3, rightIndex-5
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
In less function
```

---

---

How to resolve this problem?

*Cygwin is not supporting coredump trace format using gdb, trace is provided(above)*

Comment: Will be easier to help if you post the relevant stack trace

Comment: @yankee2905 Please read my Note(below) in the query. I can share complete code

Comment: We can't know if `cache->records` is valid. Why do you use `void`? Why do you send the size twice, `list->size` and `listSize`?

Comment: @Stargateur Because `List` is an abstraction accepting any particular type of ordered items. `List<T>` in java. Kya kare bhai, Interviewer is asking such questions at Arista networks

Comment: @overexchange Why two stars? `void *` is enough in this case.

Comment: @Stargateur array of `void*` is `void **`, where each `void*` points to that object. For example - object(`Record`) in my case. ##1) With `void*`, `List` abstraction takes an effort of creating an object, which is code smell again and breaks abstraction ##2) Luckily for me, For algo like mergesort, when you perform `merge()`, the jump between `array` & `aux` is very lightweight

Comment: @Stargateur Here is the working code on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151507/mergesort-database) for more details on my above comment

Comment: @overexchange I am currently writing an implementation would you that I post it here or in code review?

Comment: @Stargateur 1) If your implementation compiles and runs successfully, then codereview to further optimise. 2) To troubleshoot go for SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two for loops in merge should start at low, not at zero. The second for loop starting at 0 is probably causing the segmentation fault. The first for loop starting at 0 shouldn't cause a segmentation fault, but it consumes extra time.

```
static void merge(....)

    /* ... */

    for(int index = low; index <= high; index++){   // low not 0
        aux[index] = array[index];
    }

    /* ... */

    for(int index = low; index <= high; index++){   // low not 0
        if(leftIndex > mid) /* ... */
        /* ... */
```

Comment: Yup code is working now, after your change suggested

Answer (score 0):

To make a generic merge sort you must not use `void **`, because you will force the user to use a nested pointer too. So your implementation is not generic here.

I propose you an implementation that use pointer arithmetic, it's not easy to understand. But I think it's better than use `int`. I change the function less in a compare function because it's more idiomatic in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef int msort_cmp(void const *a, void const *b);

static void msort_merge(char *begin, char const *end, char *copy_begin,
                        char *copy_mid, char const *copy_end, size_t size,
                        msort_cmp *cmp) {
  memcpy(copy_begin, begin, (size_t)(end - begin));

  for (char *right = copy_mid; begin < end; begin += size) {
    if (copy_begin >= copy_mid) {
      memcpy(begin, right, size);
      right += size;
    } else if (right >= copy_end) {
      memcpy(begin, copy_begin, size);
      copy_begin += size;
    } else if (cmp(right, copy_begin) > 0) {
      memcpy(begin, right, size);
      right += size;
    } else {
      memcpy(begin, copy_begin, size);
      copy_begin += size;
    }
  }
}

static void msort_partition(char *begin, char const *end, char *copy,
                            size_t size, msort_cmp *cmp) {
  size_t bytes = (size_t)(end - begin);
  if (bytes > size) {
    size_t tmp = bytes / 2;
    size_t offset = tmp - tmp % size;

    char *mid = begin + offset;
    msort_partition(begin, mid, copy, size, cmp);
    msort_partition(mid, end, copy, size, cmp);

    msort_merge(begin, end, copy, copy + offset, copy + bytes, size, cmp);
  }
}

static int msort_aux(char *begin, char const *end, size_t size,
                     msort_cmp *cmp) {
  char *copy = malloc((size_t)(end - begin));
  if (copy == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }

  msort_partition(begin, end, copy, size, cmp);

  return 0;
}

static int msort(void *begin, void const *end, size_t size, msort_cmp *cmp) {
  return msort_aux(begin, end, size, cmp);
}

static int cmp_int_aux(int const *a, int const *b) {
  if (*a < *b) {
    return 1;
  } else if (*a > *b) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

static int cmp_int(void const *a, void const *b) { return cmp_int_aux(a, b); }

static void print_int(int const *array, size_t size) {
  printf("array: ");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf(" %d", array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

static int cmp_pint(void const *a, void const *b) {
  return cmp_int(*(int *const *)a, *(int *const *)b);
}

static void print_pint(int *const *parray, size_t size) {
  printf("parray: ");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf(" %d", *parray[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

#define SIZE 42

int main(void) {
  int array[SIZE];

  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
  for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    array[i] = rand() % SIZE - SIZE / 2;
  }

  print_int(array, SIZE);
  msort(array, array + SIZE, sizeof *array, &cmp_int);
  print_int(array, SIZE);

  int *parray[SIZE];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    array[i] = rand() % SIZE - SIZE / 2;
    parray[i] = array + i;
  }

  print_pint(parray, SIZE);
  msort(parray, parray + SIZE, sizeof *parray, &cmp_pint);
  print_pint(parray, SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Just by seeing `cmp()`  I can say your code is not generic

Comment: Why would a user(`main()`) care about memory size between `parray` and `parray+SIZE`? You are exposing implementation details

Comment: User(`main()`) is only suppose to know, how much memory to allocate for each element in `List`. `List` abstraction should not care about , 1) which object is coming in? 2) How much memory to allocate(`merge_aux()`) for that array of objects?

Comment: Best way for us to learn writing abstraction is to criticize this [code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151507/mergesort-database). Trust me and go ahead

Comment: @overexchange Take a closer look about `int (*msort_cmp)(void const *a, void const *b); ` and the cast `(msort_cmp)&cmp`. I use this implementation with `int` and `int *`, do you even read all and test before saying it's not generic? In my opinion, I don't expose an implementation detail, like algorithm in C++. I take the begin and the end, I could do something else, it's can be easily changed. You are not clear with your third comment. Sorry, but I think that my code is far better than yours, trust me. And stop spamming comment, do only one!

Comment: My third comment asks you to take out loopholes for improvement

Comment: How can a good `List` abstraction have its (representation+usage)  as well as user code?

Comment: @overexchange What you say don't make sense.